# PHP Namespace issues

Tags: php, namespaces

I am creating a system where we will use the composer autoload. When running in the composer update terminal, it generated the vendor directory. The initial structure looks like this:

[image]

The autoload.json, looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "projeto/braspag-sdk",
    "description": "SDK de integração com a loja virtual",
    "type" : "library",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Nome da empresa - Setor de TI",
            "email": "ti@empresa.com.br"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Projeto\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1"
    }
}
```

To test if everything was OK, I created a directory called authentication / Autenticacao.php. Look:

```
<?php
namespace Projeto\Autenticacao;

class Autenticacao{

    public function __construct(){
        echo "vamos testar";
    }

}
```

When I test locally, it works, but remotely gives an error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Projeto\Autenticacao' not found in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\projetos\braspag\index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main}
> thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\projetos\braspag\index.php on line 5

See below how is index.php:

```
 <?php
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    ini_set('display_startup_erros',1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

use Projeto\Autenticacao\Autenticacao;
use Projeto\Autorizacao\Autorizacao;

require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

$autorizacao = new Autorizacao;
$autenticar = new Autenticacao;
```

The remote directory looks like this: [www.site.com/braspag](http://www.site.com/braspag). Composer.json was generated in the "/" directory on the remote server. Do you have to copy the files that were generated in that directory (composer.json, composer.lock and the vendor directory) and put it in the directory where the files are located (/ httpdocs / braspag)? I did that and it didn't work either.

Comment: can you share the Marketplace\Authentication class namespace?

Comment: You need to move the `require` to occur before your `use Projecto...` statements. The autoload.php must execute before you attempt to refer to any of the classes or namespaces it defines.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the full path of the class as below:

```
use httpdocs\braspag\src\Marketplace\Authentication;
```

Inside your `Authentication` class

```
namespace httpdocs\braspag\src\Marketplace;
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I made the adjustments, but the error continues. I rephrased my question, as I noticed that it works locally, but not remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Check File name first latter is Capital and namespace first name is Capital then use full path as follow

use httpdocs\braspag\src\Marketplace\Authentication;

and so on...